# SQL Query for hours of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a table that has a column (`datetime` datatype) recording when an order is placed.

I would like to run a query that will give a breakdown of total amount of orders per hour on any given date or date range but am unsure of the best way to write the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, OrderDate) AS [Hour], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [Orders]
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate --or whatever criteria
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, OrderDate)
```

Comment: nice job with the WHERE statement.  I completely left it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
;WITH OrdersPerHour AS
(
   SELECT
      CAST(OrderDate AS DATE) 'OrderDate',
      DATEPART(HOUR, OrderDate) AS 'Hour',
      SalesAmount
   FROM
      dbo.YourOrderTable
)
SELECT 
   OrderDate, Hour, 
   COUNT(*),          -- number of orders
   SUM(SalesAmount)   -- sum of the amounts for those orders
FROM 
   OrdersPerHour
WHERE
   OrderDate = '20120113'   -- or whatever you're looking for
GROUP BY
   OrderDate, Hour
```

Not sure if you mean the total sum of the order amounts - or the number of orders - when you say *breakdown of total amount of orders per hour* - if you need the count, just use `COUNT(*)` instead of the `SUM(SalesAmount)` I put in my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEPART` and `GROUP BY` to get this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Hour, DateField), COUNT(*)
FROM Orders
WHERE Date = @DateParam -- or your range check here
GROUP BY DATEPART(Hour, Datefield)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be as simple as this:

```
    SELECT
         [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,DateTimeField)
        ,Orders = COUNT(*)
    FROM
        tblORDERS
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART(HOUR,DateTimeField)
```